# How does a slope affect stopping distance?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

We are taught 2/4 second rule when we learn to drive. But shouldn't it become even more than 2/4 seconds when driving on a decline in the mountains?

Now, I think we can agree that indeed a declining road would make the stopping distance longer, and inclining road - shorter. But by how much?

Is there a formula where we can just plug in:

- vehicle speed
- stopping distance at above speed at a flat road
- slope in %

In order to get a stopping distance? And would it carry over to trains/trams/bikes/bicycles as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force of friction is directly proportional to the normal force of the road on the car. So the stopping force decreases according to:

$F_f = \mu N = \mu mg\cos(\theta)$

Where $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction and $m$ is the mass of the car.

The steepest roads you'll generally encounter are still <10% which is about $5^o$. Since $\cos(5) = 0.996$, you'll only see about a 0.4% decrease in stopping power when going downhill. When you compare this with the uncertainty in $\mu$, which can vary by 30% or more depending on weather/road conditions, this is inconsequential.

The tangential acceleration due to gravity is also a factor, $F_{gt} = mg\sin(\theta)$, and $\sin(5^o) = 0.087$ meaning you have to stop an additional 8% of the weight of the car (note this is not quite the same as stopping an 8% heavier car on flat ground).

Overall don't expect your stopping distance to change much on an incline - weather/road conditions have a **much** bigger influence.

Comment: Sin 5 degrees is 0.087, not 0.0087. But you are right that if you are going down a hill with a slope of x%, the brakes have to overcome an additional force of about x% of the weight of the car.

Comment: @alephzero thanks - corrected

Answer (score 0):

The "2 second rule" is mainly about your reaction time when the vehicle in front brakes, and that doesn't depend on the slope of the road.

The reduction in braking efficiency affects both vehicles in the same way (assuming they are have similar designs of course) so the increase in stopping distance is the same for both.

Of course if the vehicles are different you have to use common sense. For example If you are riding a bike behind a car travelling downhill at constant speed, you will *already* be braking, otherwise you would accelerating and collide with the car, so the maximum *additional* braking force you can use is reduced. But the car is probably using its *engine,* running at high RPM with the the driver's foot off the gas pedal, as a brake to maintain constant speed, and the full power of the brakes is available in addition to the engine braking effect.

Comment: "reduction in braking efficiency affects both vehicles in the same way" if they hit something hard, and you don't, then your braking distance would be longer than theirs. The 2 second rule becomes 4 second rule in adverse weather - I always thought it's because of worse grip, and not necessary only because of worse visibility, but with the rest of your post I agree fully straightaway